# Why is postgreSQL storing a decimal field as a BigDecimal hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have the following model/table in rails3/postgreSQL:

```
create_table "admin_reports", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "report"
  t.decimal  "result"
  t.string   "result_type"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

On production, AdminReports.result is not storing the decimal but rather a hash:

AdminReport.last

```
=> #<AdminReport id: 4, report: "dau", result: #<BigDecimal:cbca0f0,'0.8E1',4(8)>, result_type: "percentage", created_at: "2012-02-28 22:05:15", updated_at: "2012-02-28 22:05:15">
```

Where I would expect to see:

AdminReport.last

```
=> #<AdminReport id: 4, report: "dau", result: 10.10, result_type: "percentage", created_at: "2012-02-28 22:05:15", updated_at: "2012-02-28 22:05:15">
```

In the rails console, even if I try to set the result field manually like so:

```
@a = AdminReport.last
@a.result = 8.89
@a.save
```

It still shows AdminReport.result as a BigDecimal hash. Any ideas what's going on here?

Thanks

Comment: That's just what a big decimal outputs when you call .inspect on it (which is what the console does).

Comment: So should I not be using decimal as the field? What field should I be using so it actually outputs the value (10.10) for example? Strangely, it wasn't doing this locally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using a decimal column:

```
create_table "admin_reports", :force => true do |t|
  #...
  t.decimal  "result"
  #...
end
```

That usually means that you want to use a fixed number of decimal places so you probably want to specify the `:precision` and `:scale` options as well. When ActiveRecord sees a decimal column, it converts the value to Ruby's BigDecimal so that you can maintain the desired number of decimal places while in Ruby-land; if AR used a floating point value then you'd run into all the usual floating point problems and you could end up pulling one value out of the database and putting a different one back **without intentionally changing it**, using BigDecimal avoids the problem entirely.

When you see this:

```
#<BigDecimal:cbca0f0,'0.8E1',4(8)>
```

You're just seeing the standard `inspect` output from BigDecimal. If you use `to_s` (or `"#{...}"`), you'll see something more familiar.

So there's nothing to worry about. If you need to use non-integer arithmetic but don't want all the problems of floating point then a decimal column (with `:precision` and `:scale`) is the right choice.

Comment: Thanks, how do I got about using a field that supports 2 decimals w precision and :scale?

Comment: @AnApprentice: You'd want `:scale => 2` for that. And maybe have a look at the PostgreSQL documentation as well: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL

Comment: Just to point out that in newer Rails versions you will still see the number in `BigDecimal` notation only without the full hash, just need to use `.to_s` method and everything will be fine.